# Replace text of dragged element

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am utilizing the native HTML5 drag and drop functionality and am trying to replace the default text displayed when the link is clicked and dragged.

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="www.somewhere.com">Somewhere</a></li>
</ul>
```

When clicked and dragged the "ghost" element displays:

```
Somewhere
www.somewhere.com
```

Is there someway to change the text via JS and, even better, change the appearance via CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you little bit more explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: When you click, hold then drag a link (pretty much any link on any webpage) the you don't drag the actual element but instead a 'ghost' element/component.  Depending on which browser you're using it will differ, I use Chrome on Mac.  I want to change the text of the 'ghost' element that is on the cursor when you are dragging something.

Answer (score -2):

You can check this example, when you start drag it change the text of anchor.

https://jsbin.com/wuwivisebo/edit?html,output

The same way you can change the style and other stuff.

Comment: This changes the draggable element, I want to change the element that appears when you are dragging the element.